# LSTM evaluation metric MAE explanation

Tags: performance, lstm

I have a hard time understanding the LSTM model performance as I summarize my model as follow:

```
X_train.shape
(120, 7, 11)
y_train.shape
(120,)
X_test.shape
(16, 7, 11)
y_test.shape
 (16,)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(100, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences = True))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate = 0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(20))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate = 0.2))          
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001), metrics = ['mae'])

history = model.fit(
X_train, y_train, 
epochs=60,
batch_size=5,
verbose= 0,
validation_split = 0.1,
shuffle=False
)
```

Based on the below plots, both MSE and MAE decrease in the training process and their corresponding values are near zero.

[image: mse]
[image: mae]

However the prediction is not precise enough as I realize:

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
[0.04673878103494644, 0.15574690699577332]
```

[image: prediction]

So my question is, how does really my model perform? I mean how can interpret its performance,since both MSE and MAE seem to be low but the prediction values are not quite convincing.

Answer (score 2):

You see an MSE of about 0.03, which corresponds to an average error of 0.17 (taking the square root, since MSE is mean squared error). What you see in your time series is errors between 0.0 and 0.4, which seems reasonable.

I would train for longer and see if you can get your MSE down further (MSE is more sensitive to big outliers). I don't think 60 epochs is a very high number.

Also I note that you only seem to have 120 data points - this may be a bit low to train a multi layer LSTM model, these models perform best with a lot of data. How much data do you need? - there is no hard and fast rule, but your LSTM has about 4000 weights, one rule of thumb I have heard is to use 3* the number of weights - so 12,000 datapoints - source here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_minimum_sample_size_required_to_train_a_Deep_Learning_model-CNN

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have some question... First how would you say that the MSE is 0.03, since the MSE is 0.049 on test data and ranges from almost 0.02 to 0.1 on train and validation  data. Second how does outliers relate to number of epochs? as I understand all of my train data with all of the outliers feed forward to the network in each epoch, so their impact would contribute anyway. Last but not least, is there a rule of thumb for the number of train data for the LSTM networks considering the number of features?

Comment: If the MSE is 0.049 then that suggests that the errors are of the order of 0.049^0.5 which is 0.7 (I was just reading 0.03 off your graph).
With more training epochs, and more data, you may find that the network trains better and errors reduce. I added a note on the number of datapoints to the main answer.